# Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/onedrive.list

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I am new to Ubuntu and arrived to this unknown error:

```
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/onedrive.list
```

Comment: The error message tells you the line number which contains an error, plus the file where the error exists.  You need to correct that file; someone with `sudo` rights on your box has created an invalid file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` (a directory which is empty on clean install so `onedrive.list` was added).  The command `sudo` elevates your privileges & does not belong in source files.

Comment: it's not working with this command

Comment: E: Type 'onedrive' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/onedrive.list

Answer (score 0):

Lines in source lists can ether start with `deb` e.g.:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main
```

or with `deb-src` e.g.:

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main
```

`deb` and `deb-src`are known as [archive tyoes](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Archive_type) ... These are expected at the very beginning of each repository source line.

They shouldn't be replaced by any other word or else that other replacement will be parsed as an archive type ... Hence the error message you see:

> Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/onedrive.list

Which means there is the word `sudo` at the beginning of line number 1 in the source file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/onedrive.list`.

To solve this edit that file to comment out that line be prepending `#`  to it, deleting it or correcting its format and save the changes ... Then run `sudo apt update` afterwords.